# Which main physics journals publish the main types of physics papers?

Tags: soft-question

I'm thinking of writing a paper on a new way of deriving the conservation of energy from symmetry principles and the Galilean transformations, but I'm not sure where to publish. Taking a look at AJP, it tends to be there for teachers at universities writing papers on how best to teach a certain topic, and to clear up misunderstandings. On the other hand, my paper certainly isn't to do with cutting edge physics, but merely another approach to something that is understood in other ways, and therefore not worthy of being published in Physics review, say.

So where should I publish?

More generally, how are the papers physicists publish mainly categorised, and which main journals publish papers in these areas?

Comment: I can see how some may vote to have this question closed as being too subjective; I don't think it is because certain types of journals definitely publish certain types of physics papers only

Comment: It's not so much subjective as it is possibly off topic, at least in my opinion. But we'll see what the community thinks.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky yes it's borderline, since it doesn't fall into the type of questions that can be asked, nor those those that shouldn't in the faq. On the other hand, it does say: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" which is true in my case - I want to publish a physics paper.

Comment: Subjectivity would not be the problem here. But it seem to ask for a list of an arbitrary number of answers. Maybe this is the kind of list we can tolerate, but... Also, genuinely *new* work in classical mechanics can indeed be published in good journals. As old as it is, the field in not static.

Comment: Related closed question http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19027/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic that question was closed here because it was concerned with mathematics journals.

Comment: Wait, I just recommended AJP, and I see you know about it. If you think you are clearing up "misunderstandings" it is best not to publish at all-- publications are not the best way to get people unconfused about something, that's what the internet is for.

Answer (score 2):

If your argument is nice pedagogically, and very original, it might be suitable for the "American Journal of Physics". But in general, if you just want to get it out, you can just put in on Arxiv under "General Physics", as various people have done with pedagogical innovations. Or else you can just write it in a blog, or elsewhere online.

In the case you mention, I doubt there is significantly room for improvement.